# I want to show my specific array on search functionality in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to filter my array on search functionality so that on eventListener(onChange) only the desired array data show. I have tried to use filter method but it's really troubling for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Services</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <h2>API</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="button">
            <button onclick="allData(servicesData)">All</button>
            <button onclick="filterIt(servicesData)">Heapware</button>
            <button onclick="webDeveloper(servicesData)">Web Developer</button>
        </div>

        <div class="search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search An Item">
           
            
        </div>
        <br>
            <br>
    
    <div class="services">
        
    </div>
</div>
    
   <script src="./services.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

const api = [
    {
        id:1,
        title:"Web-Developer",
        detail:"Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia facilis aspernatur placeat dignissimos aliquam quis Reiciendis odio quasillo atque vel corporis voluptatibus sequi numquam aliquid veniam doloremque cupiditate asperiores!",
        img:"./pic.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:2,
        title:"Android",
        detail:"Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia facilis aspernatur placeat dignissimos aliquam quis Reiciendis odio quasillo atque vel corporis voluptatibus sequi numquam aliquid veniam doloremque cupiditate asperiores!",
        img:"./pic1.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:3,
        title:"SEO Expert",
        detail:"Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia facilis aspernatur placeat dignissimos aliquam quis Reiciendis odio quasillo atque vel corporis voluptatibus sequi numquam aliquid veniam doloremque cupiditate asperiores!",
        img:"./pic6.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:4,
        title:"Game Developer",
        detail:"Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia facilis aspernatur placeat dignissimos aliquam quis Reiciendis odio quasillo atque vel corporis voluptatibus sequi numquam aliquid veniam doloremque cupiditate asperiores!",
        img:"./pic3.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:5,
        title:"Networking",
        detail:"Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia facilis aspernatur placeat dignissimos aliquam quis Reiciendis odio quasillo atque vel corporis voluptatibus sequi numquam aliquid veniam doloremque cupiditate asperiores!",
        img:"./pic5.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:6,
        title:"Social Media",
        detail:"Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia facilis aspernatur placeat dignissimos aliquam quis Reiciendis odio quasillo atque vel corporis voluptatibus sequi numquam aliquid veniam doloremque cupiditate asperiores!",
        img:"./pic.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:7,
        title:"Youtuber",
        detail:"Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia facilis aspernatur placeat dignissimos aliquam quis Reiciendis odio quasillo atque vel corporis voluptatibus sequi numquam aliquid veniam doloremque cupiditate asperiores!",
        img:"./pic6.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:8,
        title:"FrontEnd Developer",
        detail:"Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia facilis aspernatur placeat dignissimos aliquam quis Reiciendis odio quasillo atque vel corporis voluptatibus sequi numquam aliquid veniam doloremque cupiditate asperiores!",
        img:"./pic2.jpg"
    },
    {
        id:8,
        title:"BackEnd Developer",
        detail:"Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia facilis aspernatur placeat dignissimos aliquam quis Reiciendis odio quasillo atque vel corporis voluptatibus sequi numquam aliquid veniam doloremque cupiditate asperiores!",
        img:"./pic5.jpg"
    },
]



let main = document.querySelector(".main");
function data(usman){

  let card= usman.map((umar)=>{
       return `
        <div class="card1">
        <img src=${umar.img}></img>
        <h2>${umar.title}</h2>
        <p>${umar.detail}</p>
        <button>Search</button>
        </div>  
        `
    })
    main.innerHTML = card;
}
data(api);



function allData(api){
    let main = document.querySelector(".main");
   let card = api.map((ser)=>{
             return`
                <div class="card1">
                <img src=${ser.img}></img>
                <h2>${ser.title}</h2>
                <p>${ser.detail}</p>
                <button>Search</button>
                </div>
                `
            })
            main.innerHTML = card;
}



function show(api){
const main = document.querySelector(".main");
api.find((ser)=>{
    if(ser.id === 6){

        let card=
        `
        <div class="card1">
        <img src=${ser.img}></img>
        <h2>${ser.title}</h2>
        <p>${ser.detail}</p>
        <button>Search</button>
        </div>
        `
        main.innerHTML = card;
    }
})
}

function web(api) {
    const filteredServices = api.filter((servi) => servi.id === 8);
    let htmlTemplate = '';
    filteredServices.forEach((node) => {
      const card= `
      <div class= "card1">
          <img src=${node.img} alt="Image Available Soon" />
          <h2>${node.title}</h2>
          <p>${node.detail}</p>
      </div> `;
      htmlTemplate += card;
    });
    main.innerHTML = htmlTemplate;
}
```

I want to filter my array on search functionality so that on eventListener(onChange) only the desired array data show. I have tried to use filter method but it's really troubling for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
let card= api.map(v,i)={
if(i==6){return v}
}
```

Try to use the map function to iterate over api array then if the index within the map function = 6, assign the corresponding object to card.